# Should there be multiple _ga tracking cookies for a gtm UA tracked property containing multiple subdomains?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, subdomain, google-tag-manager

If example.com contains multiple subdomains and all of it resides in a single UA property, assuming subdomain tracking is properly set up in gtm (IE cookieDomain is set to auto and the root domain is on the referral exclusion list for google analytics), should more than one _ga cookie exist on page load when visiting subdomains?

For example, my gtm snippet is included across all subdomains and it fires a pageview UA tag properly and I visit status.example.com, should I see a _ga cookie with an example value of GA1.3.605803990.1475857272 with the status.example.com domain scope and a _ga cookie with an example value of GA1.2.1926999794.1476293458 with the example.com domain scope?

Or should there always be one _ga cookie fixed at just the root domain? I'm trying to determine why my google analytics is still reporting self referrals for both my root domain and subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track your domain and subdomains within a single property there should be a single _ga cookie. To make sure there is just one cookie the cookie domain should be set to "auto" when you create the tracker

```
ga('create','UA-XXXXXXX-X','auto');
```

which will make sure the cookie is set at the highest possible 'level'. If you get the code from the GA property settings the "auto" setting should already be in there, if you create the tracker via Google Tag Manager you need to explicitly set this via the "set fields" option where you set the field name to "cookieDomain" (GTM has an autosuggest feature that will help with the field names) and the value to "auto".